SwiftUI (Swift 6): Possible to have App without WindowGroup?
Is it possible to have an App without a explicit WindowGroup?  If I comment out the Scene around the main View in the default project, it gives "buildExpression is unavailable".  But buildExpression is a method of SceneBuilder - is a WindowGroup then always explicitly required?
I'm compiling for the iPhone simulator, not the iPad simulator, if that makes a difference.

Why do you want to do this? This sounds like an XY Problem.

If it isn’t a window, what should it be?
